# Restoring dependency via nuget in VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I created a project of `Windows Runtime Component (Universal)` type using VS2017. Project file includes package reference:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>5.2.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Everything works fine if this option is enabled: `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio`

[image]

But I have some cases (this option is disabled, build via CLI, server CI build) when this dependency is not being restored automatically during build and `project.assets.json` is missing in the `obj` folder after build. It causes a lot of errors like this: `error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported`

Is it possible to make auto restoring of package reference via project file (.csproj)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Execute `msbuild -t:restore your.sln` before building the solution to restore all packages and make sure your CI uses MSBuild 15.x.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I also need to get back compatibility w/ VS2015 which used MSBuild version lower than 15.